# Question involving profit and loss

Tags: arithmetic

A shopkeeper brought 1840 oranges for 350 dollars . He threw away 52 rotten oranges and packed the rest in boxes of 6 each . He sold these boxes at 1.85 each .calculate the total profit he made if the cost of empty boxes was 4 cents each.

My workings

Remaining oranges = $ 1840-52 = 1788 $
Number of boxes = $ 1788 / 6 = 298 boxes $

Total selling price of all the boxes = $ 298 X 1.85 = 551.30 $

Total costs for empty boxes = $ 298 X 0.04  = 11.92 $

Cost of 1788 oranges = $ 350/1840 X 1788 = 340.1086 $

Total cost = $352.0286$

Profit = $551.30 - 352.0286 = 199.27$

However , many said that my workings are wrong . Can I get help on why ? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Even if he throw away 52 oranges, he still need to pay for them.

Answer (score 1):

You used the cost of 1788 oranges as \$340.11, although he paid $350 for them (it doesn't matter that 52 of them were unusable!).

Hence the total cost is \$350 + \$11.92 = \$361.92

We conclude that the profit is \$551.30 - \$361.92 = \$189.38